# How to distribute VB6 bootstrapping files?

Tags: windows, vb6, installation

I am porting my VB6 installer to NSIS. Looking at the LST file, there is a section for bootstrapping files:

```
[Bootstrap Files]
File1=@VB6STKIT.DLL,$(WinSysPathSysFile),,,..........
File2=@COMCAT.DLL,$(WinSysPathSysFile),$(DLLSelfRegister),,......
File3=@STDOLE2.TLB,$(WinSysPathSysFile),$(TLBRegister),...........
File4=@ASYCFILT.DLL,$(WinSysPathSysFile),,,...........
File5=@OLEPRO32.DLL,$(WinSysPathSysFile),$(DLLSelfRegister),.........
File6=@OLEAUT32.DLL,$(WinSysPathSysFile),$(DLLSelfRegister),,........
File7=@msvbvm60.dll,$(WinSysPathSysFile),$(DLLSelfRegister),,...........
File8=@wshom.ocx,$(WinSysPath),$(DLLSelfRegister),$(Shared),.........
```

and another for setup1 files

```
[Setup1 Files]
File1=@drillcycles.pre,$(AppPath).......
File2=@twoz.pre,$(AppPath),.......
```

In another post, I was warned about distributing the wshom.ocx file (bootstrapping file), saying:

> "That wshom.ocx is not meant to be distributed in this way. On
>   downlevel versions of Windows this might succeed, only to break WSH
>   and other scripting on the system. Do not redist this library like
>   this. "

So, I was wondering if there are any considerations for distributing bootstrapping files? should I even distribute them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is much more relevant to some of the other files you are installing.  Windows can still run with a borked script interpreter but it can't survive when you accidentally oleaut32.dll or asyncfilt.dll.  Which for one is why these files are protected from accidental overwriting by crummy installers, the Windows file system protection feature puts the correct one back immediately.

The odds that you'll actually run your installer on a machine that requires these files to be installed are zero.  Windows 95 is gone.  The odds that you'll install the wrong version of them if such a borked machine actually exists are very high.  Which is one way to put it out of its prolonged misery.

As long as your installer has minimum counter measures in place to avoid replacing new DLLs with old copies with a simple version check then this isn't going to go wrong.  Don't worry about it.  Do consider that it is time that you stop relying on such ancient tools.

Comment: So, I am not sure how to proceed. How can I know which files have to be included and which do not?

Comment: Also, I am also not sure what is the role of bootstrapping. is this section still aplicable if I want to distribute my application with another installer? Thanks.

Comment: You can buy installer packages that sort this out for you.  Probably your best bet to rid yourself of the fud.  InstallShield for example, not otherwise an endorsement.

Comment: Ok, I imagine NSIS already comes with something like this. I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: @Peretz: NSIS engine is self-contained, it does not need "bootstrapping" of any kind. P&DW setups needs VB6 runtime just to start installing the rest of the application i.e. bootstrapping.

Comment: @wqw: Can I just get rid of all the bootstrapping files? are you sure that the VB6 runtime is not used for anything else besides bootstrapping?

Comment: @Peretz: VB6 runtime is needed for your VB6 app, not for the NSIS installer. So you'll need to ship the runtime if you plan to install on OS before Vista (which has the runtime built-in).

Comment: @wqw: so, something is not clear to me. The files in the bootstrapping section are to distribute the [Setup1 files] or are they the VB6 runtime files?

Comment: @Peretz: `msvbvm60.dll` is the VB6 runtime. It has dependency on File2 to File6 (File1 and File8 are PDW cruft). Which OS do you target? You need File2 to File6 only for win95 (and early NTs probably) as recent OSes have newer versions of these system DLLs. For 2000 and XP you only need to ship `msvbvm60.dll`. For Vista and win7 you don't have to ship anything and you can't touch these files even if you try (protected by OS). If targeting XP and above you can use registration-free COM too (xcopy deployment).

Comment: @wqw: Just to see if I understood well. I support Windows XP and above and I am developing on NSIS. File1-File6 and File8 can be erased. File7 (VB6 runtime) should be copied to System32 directory for Windows XP, and that is pretty much it. is this right?

Comment: @Peretz: Yes, and you should mark it as shared dll. You have to check your setups both on clean XP and with SP2/SP3 applied (use VirtualBox or similar VM).